# How can I make my quote randomizer more automatic and concise?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a personal quote randomizer (currently filled with filler quotes) that works exactly how I want it to: I press a button, the browser first randomizes the category, and then from that category the browser gets a random quote to display. Below is part of the JavaScript code (The actual "quote interface is created with an HTML file)

But, the adding a new category to the quote randomizer means adding to the switch statement in addition to adding said new category to the first array. I'm not lazy, but I can't help but feel that I'm missing something vital; something which can make everything more concise and efficient. Is there some way to replace the switch statement part and opt in for a different method of getting this quote? Don't worry about any of the HTML, I'm only concerned with making my javascript code cleaner. I'll also add [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dowaday/edit?html,css,js,output) in case anyone needs to see the whole thing.

```
/* ALL QUOTE CATEGORIES */
var allCategories = [
    `Finance`,
    `Gratitude`,
    `Life`,
    `Work Ethic`,
];



/* FINANCE QUOTES */
var quoteCategoryFinance = [
/*1*/   `“This is a quote about Finance” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*2*/   `“This is a second quote Finance” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*3*/   `"This is a third quote about Finance" <br /> -Person who said it`,
];



/* GRATITUDE QUOTES */
var quoteCategoryGratitude = [
/*1*/   `“This is a quote about Gratitude” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*2*/   `“This is a second quote Gratitude” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*3*/   `"This is a third quote about Gratitude" <br /> -Person who said it`,
];



/* LIFE QUOTES */
var quoteCategoryLife = [
/*1*/   `“This is a quote about Life” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*2*/   `“This is a second quote Life” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*3*/   `"This is a third quote about Life" <br /> -Person who said it`,
];  

                

/* WORK ETHIC QUOTES */
var quoteCategoryWorkEthic = [  
/*1*/   `“This is a quote about Work Ethic” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*2*/   `“This is a second quote Work Ethic” <br /> -Person who said it`,
/*3*/   `"This is a third quote about Work Ethic" <br /> -Person who said it`,
];




var randomCategory;
function getRandomCategory() {
    randomCategory = allCategories[Math.floor(Math.random()*allCategories.length)];
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = randomCategory;
}


var randomQuote;
var quoteNumber;
function getRandomQuote() {

    switch (randomCategory) {
        case `Finance`:
        quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteCategoryFinance.length);
        randomQuote = quoteCategoryFinance[quoteNumber];
        break;

        case `Gratitude`:
        quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteCategoryGratitude.length);
        randomQuote = quoteCategoryGratitude[quoteNumber];
        break;

        case `Life`:
        quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteCategoryLife.length);
        randomQuote = quoteCategoryLife[quoteNumber];
        break;

        case `Work Ethic`:
        quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteCategoryWorkEthic.length);
        randomQuote = quoteCategoryWorkEthic[quoteNumber];
        break;

        default:
        console.log(`Getting random quote did not work`);
    }

    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = randomQuote;
    document.getElementById("quote-number").innerHTML = `Quote #` + (quoteNumber + 1);
}


function giveQuote() {
getRandomCategory();getRandomQuote();
}
```

Comment: Barmar has the correct solution below, an observation about your code: You're not using the quote category for anything. It may make more sense to keep all your quotes in a single array, that way different quotes won't end up with the same quote number.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I should have been more clear, but I also display the quote category as well as the quote on the browser. You can see an example of what I mean on the jsbin I linked in the last sentence of my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object to hold the correspondence between categories and arrays of quotes.

```
var categoryQuotes = {
    "Finance": quoteCategoryFinance,
    "Gratitude": quoteCategoryGratitude,
    "Life": quoteCategoryLife,
    "Work Ethic": quoteCategoryWorkEthic
};

function getRandomQuote() {
    if (randomCategory in categoryQuotes) {
        let quotes = categoryQuotes[randomCategory];
        let quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        let randomQuote = quotes[quoteNumber];
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = randomQuote;
        document.getElementById("quote-number").innerHTML = `Quote #` + (quoteNumber + 1);
    } else {
        console.log("Getting random quote did not work");
    }
}
```

You also don't then need the array `allCategories`. You can use `Object.keys(categoryQuotes)` instead. Then you don't have to worry about them getting out of sync.